# Creating a new array, discluding an item is faster than creating a list and removing it?

Tags: c#, performance, xna, comparison

I was desperately trying to find a faster way of creating an array without one of the items in it, opposed to creating a list of those objects and removing that item.

The reason being is that my array has like 5 items on average, less most times, and creating a list just to remove one item that I no longer wanted in there, seemed way too much to me.

Since I coded my own profiler a while back, I decided to put that method, and another one I thought of, under a test, and heck are the results significant.

```
int[] a1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Method 1 (creating a list of the objects and removing the 2nd item):

```
 Profiler.Start("Method 1");
 List<int> a2 = new List<int>(a1);
 a2.RemoveAt(1);
 Profiler.Stop("Method 1");
```

Method 2 (creating an array of the same size but one, and discluding the 2nd item):

```
 Profiler.Start("Method 2");
 int[] a3 = new int[a1.Length - 1];
 int l = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++) if (a1[i] != 2) { a3[l] = a1[i]; l++; }
 Profiler.Stop("Method 2");
```

Profiler results:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/al8i6.png

**The question**
Why is the difference in performance so significant?

I never actually took the time to study the differences between an array and a list.

Comment: Is there a question inside?

Comment: Sorry guys, updated it displaying a1.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Apologies, question added.

Comment: There's no way you can reliably profile such a quickly executed bit of code. You should put it into a loop and call it thousands of times. (And then you'll have the garbage collection overhead interfering too...)

Comment: Also note that you aren't comparing like with like. Your array solution does not copy the original data into the array - it always uses an array of all zeroes.

Comment: I did that too but didn't display it here, the results aren't quite as significant, but are significant non-the-less.

Comment: As a rule, allocating and GCing memory are dominant time-hogs (unless something even bigger is going on, which in large software could well be the case). So do whatever minimizes hitting the memory manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the overhead is coming from the initialisation for the contents of the list rather than from the call to `List.RemoveAt()`.

In other words, the line `List<int> a2 = new List<int>(a1);` is dominating the time.

Here's some code that attempts to eliminate the time taken for `List.RemoveAt()` and `Array.Copy()`.

The results from a release build on my PC are:

```
LIST Elapsed: 00:00:00.4724841
ARRAY Elapsed: 00:00:00.4670488
LIST Elapsed: 00:00:00.4714016
ARRAY Elapsed: 00:00:00.4675552
LIST Elapsed: 00:00:00.4703538
ARRAY Elapsed: 00:00:00.4698310
```

which shows the times to be fairly similar.

The test program is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int[] a1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 };

            int trials = 3;
            int iterations = 10000000;

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            for (int i = 0; i < trials; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < iterations; ++j)
                {
                    List<int> a2 = new List<int>(a1);

                    sw.Start();
                    a2.RemoveAt(1);
                    sw.Stop();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("LIST Elapsed: " + sw.Elapsed);
                sw.Reset();

                for (int j = 0; j < iterations; ++j)
                {
                    int[] a3 = new int[a1.Length - 1];
                    int l = 0;

                    sw.Start();

                    for (int k = 0; k < a1.Length; k++)
                    {
                        if (a1[k] != 2)
                        {
                            a3[l] = a1[k];
                            l++;
                        }
                    }

                    sw.Stop();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("ARRAY Elapsed: " + sw.Elapsed);
                sw.Reset();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Except method 1 is removing a single item, method 2 is looping through all items and copying them excluding one of them, yet method 2 is faster? :P Thanks for the answer, and why have you used    the Array.Copy? It isn't needed since the loop does that.

Comment: @DeanReynolds No, method 1 is also copying all items up by one place. If it didn't, then it would be broken! After removing an element at index [2] then all the following elements must now occupy an element with an index one less. I'll remove the Array.Copy() (it was leftover from some other test code, but it isn't included in the timing)

Comment: Oh, also note that I was running an x64 build. It turns out that for an x86 build, method 1 is actually a tiny bit faster than method 2.

Comment: I am also x64 - but what do you think I should use, at the moment I'm sticking with method 2.

Comment: @DeanReynolds Since you've already written it, I'd go with method 2.